# Spring Cloud Stream generates unnecessary complex Kafka topologies, why?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a KStream application with a bunch of KStreams, joins and other operations. I enabled `logging.level.org.springframework.kafka.config=debug` to verify the Topology that was being generated and found out a lot of nodes that didn't make sense at all.

Then I simplified the application to just this:

```
interface ShippingKStreamProcessor {

    @Input("input")
    fun input(): KStream<Int, Customer>

}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Configuration
class ShippingKStreamConfiguration {

    @StreamListener
    fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<Int, Customer> {}

}
```

Oddly enough such a simple KStream declaration generates this complex topology:

```
2019-04-30 23:47:03.881 DEBUG 2944 --- [           main] o.s.k.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean   : Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [customer])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000003, KSTREAM-PROCESSOR-0000000002
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000004, KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000004 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000007
      <-- KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000005 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PROCESSOR-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-BRANCH-0000000003
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000007 (stores: [])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-PROCESSOR-0000000002 (stores: [])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-PROCESSOR-0000000006 (stores: [])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-BRANCHCHILD-0000000005
```

[image]

The same simple stream in a native Kafka application results in a more logical topology:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val builder = StreamsBuilder()

    val streamsConfiguration = Properties()
    streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = "kafka-shipping-service"
    streamsConfiguration[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:9092"
    streamsConfiguration[AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:8081"

    val serdeConfig = mapOf(
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG to "http://localhost:8081",
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY to TopicRecordNameStrategy::class.java.name
    )

    //val byteArraySerde = Serdes.ByteArray()
    val intSerde = Serdes.IntegerSerde()
    val customerSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<Customer>()
    customerSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false)

    val customerStream = builder.stream<Int, Customer>("customer",
        Consumed.with(intSerde, customerSerde)) as KStream<Int, Customer>

    val topology = builder.build()
    println(topology.describe())

    val streams = KafkaStreams(topology, streamsConfiguration)
    streams.start()
}
```

Topology:

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [customer])
      --> none
```

[image]

What's the reason why Spring Cloud Stream generates such a complex topology?

Comment: That is very interesting. Will look into it. One reason I can think of is because of the message conversions that the binder needs to do. So, if you can turn native decoding/encoding enabled, I think that will reduce the topology a bit. In addition to that, there are other paths in which the binder may add more topologies such as the use of DLQ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@codependent The reason why you have those extra processors in the topology is because you are using the de/serailzers provided by the framework (native decoding and encoding default to `false`). Basically, we receive the data from Kafka topic as a `byte[]` and then do the transformations internally. For these transformations, we go through a few extra processors and thus you end up with that deeper topology.

Here is a basic `StreamListener` in Java (pretty much what you have up there, but using simpler value type):

```
@StreamListener
public void process(@Input("input") KStream<Integer, String> input ) {

}
```

With the standard out of the box setting in the binder, I was able to get the same deeper topology that you have observed. However, when I modified application's configuration as shown below,

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams:
  binder.configuration:
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.useNativeDecoding: true
```

my topology is reduced as below:

```
2019-05-01 18:02:12.705 DEBUG 67539 --- [           main] o.s.k.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean   : Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [hello-1])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
```

This is still not the same as the topology that you got from the plain Kafka Streams application, but this turns out to be something that we can improve in the binder to avoid. In short, by switching to native decoding and encoding provided by Kafka Streams, you can avoid all those extra level of topologies built by the binder.

In some cases, you don't have a choice, but rely on the deserialization provided by Spring Cloud Stream, for e.g., you receive data from a producer that is based on Spring Cloud Stream that used some special serializers. I think that is true in your case since from what I remember, your producer is based on Spring Cloud Stream and that uses an Avro serializer provided by the framework. In that case, using Kafka Stream's Avro `Serde` in your processor won't work as those serializers are not compatible. So here are some of your options.

Approcah #1:

1. Make your producers use native serializers provided by Kafka.
2. Then use Serde's that use the same serializer/deserializer in your Kafka Streams application.

Approach #2:

1. Use message serializers provided by SCSt.
2. Then use the default de/serialization provided by Kafka Streams binder which is the default.

The downside of #2 is obviously what you brought up above, i.e. deeper topologies. That might be okay depending on your use cases and throughput. If this becomes a real performance issue, we can try to streamline this process when conversion is done by the framework.

With all that said, I created an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/651) in the Kafka binder to make a change in the next release of the binder. Your feedback, suggestions, up/down votes are welcomed there.

Comment: Starting with 3.0 version of Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams binder, the default deserialization is done natively by Kafka. Thus the topology generated by the Spring application is equivalent to the one generated by the native application.